# How to get back the deleted files in git? which have been deleted with this message> We found potential security vulnerabilities in your dependencies

Tags: git, github

I was faced with this message: `We found a potential security vulnerability in one of your dependencies`

And I tried to fix it by running this command in `Git`

`npm audit fix`

when it completed all the files that I had deleted and there was nothing, now I don't know how to get them back.

is there a way to get back the files?

Thanks

Comment: What files it deleted? It they weren't track by git that time or in past it will be hard...

Comment: except packages.json and some similar files not deleted the rest all deleted

Comment: So did it removed some utracked files?

Comment: Yeah it did, even in github

Comment: If the file was in github it had to be tracked - unless you push with force it should be still there. Is repo public maybe? Could you paste output of`git status`, `git log`, `git branch -a` and `git reflog`?

Comment: Yeah, the old version is still there. the new version I tried to push has been deleted. even the git status or git log don't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240441/discussion-between-kosciej16-and-john).

Comment: Note that `npm audit` is *not a Git command*. Git is acting only as a file-depot (technically as a *commit*-depot, but for the moment just think of it as the "warehouse" either way). The npm code then fishes stuff out of the warehouse and other stuff from other warehouses and assembles it all into a finished product to put into use. The finished product is where the security flaw is. Whether that's because of instructions stored in *your* warehouse, or in others, Git isn't really involved: Git just provides the warehouses, not the files themselves.

Comment: Given the nature of a Git repository, if you don't `git push -f`, you still have *every version of every file ever*. The "warehouse" is add-only: when someone comes to take something out, they take out a *copy* of the files. Your latest set-of-files omit some files, but *earlier* sets are frozen for all time, so all you have to do is "go back in time" to one of the earlier sets.